# How to check for a certain value and then exchange to money values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bank

I was playing around with arrays and I wanted to create a program in which you enter the value of money and then check how many coins or bank notes you need to fill that value.

In case you enter 650 you should get one for: 500 one for 100 and one for 50.
That's the program I got so far, but somehow it only prints out all of the values stored in bankovci array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[]bills = {500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
    int amount=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vnesi znesek: "));
    int sum=0;
    System.out.print("We will need bills for: ");
    while(sum<=amount)
    {
    for(int i=0; i < bills.length; i++)
    {
        if(amount-bills[i]>=0)
        {
            sum+=bills[i];

        }
        else if(amount-sum>bills[i])
        {
            i+=1;
        }System.out.print(bills[i]+", ");
    }


    }}}
```

### Edit

In case I enter 650 or any other number I get the following output:

> We will need bills for: 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1,

Comment: Please post your code in English and also the exact output that you are getting.

Comment: Any reason for   i+=1; in your else case..

Comment: @saravanakumar I've added i+=1 to query for further value in case that this value is out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cleaner ways of solving this problem (without using the break keyword), as I am sure other people will post.  But to help you understand where you had trouble, here is a modified version of the code that you supplied.  Notice that I changed the if statement, and removed the else block.  I also had to add a break to exit the for loop early, which is what I think you were trying to use the i+1 for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]bills = {500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
    int amount=250;
    int sum=0;
    System.out.print("We will need bills for: ");
    while(sum<amount)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < bills.length; i++)
        {
            if(sum+bills[i] <= amount)
            {
                sum+=bills[i];

                System.out.print(bills[i]+", ");

                break;
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: if `sum+bills[i] <= amount` This is also run through "while" if the exact amount is found. E. G. 650. Must be `sum+bills[i] < amount`

Comment: @moskito-x. Thank you, I missed the opportunity for an infinite loop.  I changed the while to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

```
int[] numbers = new int[bills.length];
int total = amount;
for (int i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = total / bills[i]; // Will perform integer division
    total = total % bills[i]; // equivalent to total -= numbers[i]*bills[i];
}
```

It will work as long as bills is a decreasing array (starting with the highest avalable note).
`numbers` will contain the number of notes of the `i`-th bank note value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical mistake i will show you:

1. amount - bill[0] >=0?  -> 650 - 500 >= 0?  : yes , sum = 500   print: "500, "
2. amount - bill[1] >=0?  -> 650 - 200 >= 0?  : yes , sum = 700    print: "200, "
   etc...

you should change your for loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bills.length;) {
    if(amount >= bills[i]) {
        system.out.print(bills[i] +", ");
        amount -= bills[i];
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

i think this should do it :D

Edit:
You should remove the

```
while(sum<=amount)
```

when you try my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                        public static void main(String[] args) {
                            List<Integer> availNote = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            availNote.addAll(Arrays.asList(500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1));
                            System.out.println(availNote);
                            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                            int znesek=Integer.parseInt(in.next());
                            System.out.print("Potrebovali bi bankovce za: " );
                            List<Integer> splitedAmount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while(znesek != 0){
                            for(int i=0; i < availNote.size(); i++)
                            {
                                if(znesek >= availNote.get(i) ){
                                    splitedAmount.add(availNote.get(i));
                                    znesek  = znesek - availNote.get(i);
                                }
                            }
                            }
                            System.out.println(splitedAmount);

                        }
```